# Can I get Castle Windsor to complain when I try to Resolve a single component which is multiply registered?

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

If I register two components for the same service, e.g.

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IThing>.ImplementedBy<Thing1>(),
    Component.For<IThing>.ImplementedBy<Thing2>())
```

I find it surprising that if I `Resolve` a dependency on `IThing` or ask it to be resolved manually, Windsor will simply pick one to give me (the first, or `Thing1`, it appears).

I understand this might be beneficial in some cases to allow one registrar to "override" another by getting first in the list of registered components.

Is there a way to specify that when the `IThing` service is resolved singly that an exception should be thrown in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Windsor will by default use the first component as default for any given service and it not throwing but working like that is a really powerful feature used in some advanced scenarios like decorators, of chain of responsibility pattern.

What would be your reason to throw in those cases?

Anyway, if you're really confident that's what you want, I'd write a test that grabs all handlers from the container

```
container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object))
```

And then you can inspect them and see if any `Service` is exposed by more than a single handler and act accordingly.

Comment: My concern is that a developer can easily specify that he wants one IThing or many IThings (e.g. IThing[]).  We may be loading plugins from 3rd parties, and were they to install their own IThing handlers, we might have a hard-to-diagnose situation where they wonder "why isn't my IThing getting used". It would be a concern if the configuration were busted and something we thought was a global service was in fact being fought over. If I understand correctly, your test would preclude users from getting IThing[] collections as well.

Comment: The test would do what you tell it to. You can add special case for collections

Answer (score 0):

You can create an implementation of `IHandlerSelector` that has an opinion about resolving `IThing`s, throwing if more than one handler is available for your `IThing` service.

You can read more about handler selectors [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Handler-Selectors.ashx).

The handler selector could be registered during development only to avoid anything going more wrong than necessary in production :)

Another strategy, which is one I usually follow, is to create a couple of automated tests that load the container in all possibly configurations (environment/customer), and then do a couple of assertions on it.

Assuming your container is fully loaded, something like

```
Assert.That(container.ResolveAll<IThing>(), Has.Length.EqualTo(1));
```

would suffice.

Comment: `IHandlerSelector`s won't fulfil the requirement like you describe that. They are handed all assignable handlers, not just handlers explicitly registered for requested type so you'd need to take that into account. Otherwise reasonable approach although I'd rather do that in a test to fail fast.